# Releasing properties in Xcode 4.2 Beta?

Tags: xcode

I am in the habit of using "private properties" to hold objects and releasing them by setting them to nil in a method called by dealloc and viewDidUnload.

The Analyze function of Xcode 4.0.2 recognizes this and I don't get any warnings.

I just switched to Xcode 4.2 Beta because I want to add some IOS5 functionality, and all of a sudden I'm getting tons of memory leak warnings for all my allocs. It seems that the Analyze function of 4.2 does not recognize that these objects are actually released. It is impossible to find real leaks in this situation.

Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: Xcode4.2 and iOS5 are under NDA

Comment: You should watch the WWDC videos or ask your question in the apple dev forums.

Comment: XCode 4.2 for Lion is now publicly available and exhibits the same issue, so I think the question can be re-opened. I'm eagerly waiting for the answer too!

Answer (score 0):

xcode 4.2 introduces automatic reference counting, so as long as you write your code properly, you wont need to `release` or `autorelease` anymore, and you wont get memory leaks